# File Not Found when running PHP with Nginx

Tags: php, nginx

Recently I installed the latest version of Nginx and looks like I'm having hard time running PHP with it.

Here is the configuration file I'm using for the domain:

```
server {
listen       80;
server_name  localhost;

location / {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index  index.php;
}

error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
location = /50x.html {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
    include        fastcgi_params;
}
```

}

Here is the error I'm getting on the error log file:

```
FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream
```

Comment: why fastcgi_pass before the fastcgi settings ?

Comment: I don't know, these are the basic config I got when I first installed Nginx.

Comment: does switching it as last statement changes anything?

Comment: `fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;` why the word `/scripts` ?

Comment: For me it was the php-fpm.sock file pointing at the old version /run/php5.6/php-fpm.sock instead of /run/php7.1/php-fpm.sock

Comment: Make sure that the configuration file is valid when you make changes to the config file with: `nginx -t`. Otherwise, changes in the config file won't load.

Comment: See my answer in [here](https://serverfault.com/a/1101518/948616) Maybe your problem is similar to mine.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

Try another *fastcgi_param* something like

```
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /usr/share/nginx/html$fastcgi_script_name;
```

Comment: Solved the problem. Your help is appriciated sir.

Comment: or use the $document_root instead of an absolute path, it is mentioned I think in the wiki

Comment: I would've given `+1` if you explained as to why this happens in the first place

Comment: In 1.6+ `$document_root$fastcgi_script_name` seems to be correct way AFAIK, but why?

Comment: Just wondering how can you debug this? (The message in nginx error.log is not really helpful and I get nothing in php5-fpm.log), thanks.

Comment: solves my problem when your `index.php` script runs but still getting `404` status.

Comment: @Tom how's wanting to know why it works being greedy?

Comment: @samayo I'm not sure what was in my head back then, but, I'm sure it was just a joke ;)

Comment: Ah! This one saved my life! Been searching for a solution for 2 hours now!!! Thanks a lot!

Comment: https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/#fastcgi-path-in-script-filename

Comment: A combination of deagh's and Richard's answers made it work.

Answer (score 60):

I had the "file not found" problem, so I moved the "root" definition up into the "server" bracket to provide a default value for all the locations. You can always override this by giving any location it's own root.

```
server {
    root /usr/share/nginx/www;
    location / {
            #root /usr/share/nginx/www;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Alternatively, I could have defined root in both my locations.

Comment: This is the one that solved it for me, the accepted answer didn't.

Comment: this solves the issue, please try this too if the above doesn't fix the problem

Comment: Thank you So much

Comment: This solved the same issue for me Ubuntu 18.04.2, nginx v1.16 php7.3-fpm

Comment: For me it was a OWNER problem, I copied from another user's dir, so just CHOWN the files

Answer (score 19):

Probably it's too late to answer but a couple things since this is a really annoying error. Following solution worked on Mac OS X Yosemite.

1. It's the best if you have

> fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

2. The include with fast cgi params should go above that line.
3. All your directories down to the PHP file you're executing (including that file too) should have `a+x` permissions, e.g.

> ```
> sudo chmod a+x /Users/
> sudo chmod a+x /Users/oleg/
> sudo chmod a+x /Users/oleg/www/
> sudo chmod a+x /Users/oleg/www/a.php
> ```

Comment: Thanks. Adding `fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;` above the include did the trick for me on Mac OS X Sierra.

Answer (score 15):

I had been having the same issues, 
And during my tests, I have faced both problems:

1º: "File not found"

and

2º: 404 Error page

And I found out that, in my case:

**I had to mount volumes for my public folders both on the Nginx volumes and the PHP volumes.**

If it's mounted in **Nginx** and is not mounted in **PHP**, it will give: "**File not found**"

Examples (Will show "File not found error"):

```
services:
  php-fpm:
    build:
      context: ./docker/php-fpm
  nginx:
    build:
      context: ./docker/nginx
    volumes:
        #Nginx Global Configurations
      - ./docker/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
      - ./docker/nginx/conf.d/:/etc/nginx/conf.d

        #Nginx Configurations for you Sites:

        # - Nginx Server block
      - ./sites/example.com/site.conf:/etc/nginx/sites-available/example.com.conf
        # - Copy Public Folder:
      - ./sites/example.com/root/public/:/var/www/example.com/public
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    depends_on:
      - php-fpm
    restart: always
```

If it's mounted in **PHP** and is not mounted in **Nginx**, it will give a **404 Page Not Found error**.

Example (Will throw 404 Page Not Found Error):

```
version: '3'

services:
  php-fpm:
    build:
      context: ./docker/php-fpm
    volumes:
      - ./sites/example.com/root/public/:/var/www/example.com/public
  nginx:
    build:
      context: ./docker/nginx
    volumes:
        #Nginx Global Configurations
      - ./docker/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
      - ./docker/nginx/conf.d/:/etc/nginx/conf.d

        #Nginx Configurations for you Sites:

        # - Nginx Server block
      - ./sites/example.com/site.conf:/etc/nginx/sites-available/example.com.conf
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    depends_on:
      - php-fpm
    restart: always
```

And **this would work just fine (mounting on both sides)** (Assuming everything else is well configured and you're facing the same problem as me):

```
version: '3'

services:
  php-fpm:
    build:
      context: ./docker/php-fpm
    volumes:
      # Mount PHP for Public Folder
      - ./sites/example.com/root/public/:/var/www/example.com/public
  nginx:
    build:
      context: ./docker/nginx
    volumes:
        #Nginx Global Configurations
      - ./docker/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
      - ./docker/nginx/conf.d/:/etc/nginx/conf.d

        #Nginx Configurations for you Sites:

        # - Nginx Server block
      - ./sites/example.com/site.conf:/etc/nginx/sites-available/example.com.conf
        # - Copy Public Folder:
      - ./sites/example.com/root/public/:/var/www/example.com/public
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    depends_on:
      - php-fpm
    restart: always
```

Also here's a Full working example project using Nginx/Php, for serving multiple sites:
https://github.com/Pablo-Camara/simple-multi-site-docker-compose-nginx-alpine-php-fpm-alpine-https-ssl-certificates

***I hope this helps someone,
And if anyone knows more about this please let me know,
Thanks!***

Comment: I know this is an old answer, but it helped me. I had changed a path in the nginx section of my compose file, and forgot to reflect the same change in the php-fpm section. Thanks for pointing this to me, I was starting to be quite fed up!

Comment: @Antoine I know this is a late response, but I recently faced the same issue. The answer above worked for me, I just don't understand why we need to mount in BOTH Nginx and PHP... do you have insight on this?

Comment: @Dimitri that's simply because those are two different containers. There must be a way to define common variables, but to be honest, I don't know enough !

Answer (score 4):

The website will show "**File Not Found**" error.

[image]

You should check this configure file: /etc/nginx/nginx.conf (error_log) to get the nginx webservice log location.
Then check nginx log: **/var/log/nginx/error.log** to get the root cause:

- Keyword: FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown"
- Root cause: php-fpm service's account: apache doesn't have access permission to open webapps directory

**Step 0.** Find your root directory:
open /etc/nginx/nginx.conf file and find `root` keyword

Root directory: /var/lib/nginx/webapps/
[image]

**Step 1.** Make sure apache account can access the ROOT directory.

```
sudo -u apache ls -l /var/lib/nginx/webapps/
```

**Step 2.** chmod a+x permission for all ROOT folder

```
sudo chmod a+x /var/
sudo chmod a+x /var/lib/
sudo chmod a+x /var/lib/nginx/
sudo chmod a+x /var/lib/nginx/webapps/
```

Answer (score 3):

I just spent like 40 minutes trying to debug a non-working /status with:

```
$ SCRIPT_NAME=/status SCRIPT_FILENAME=/status QUERY_STRING= REQUEST_METHOD=GET cgi-fcgi -bind -connect /var/run/php5-fpm.sock
```

It just produced "File not found" error, while the actual scripts (that are found on the filesystem) worked just fine.

Turned out, I had a couple of orphaned processes of php5-fpm. After I killed everything and restarted php5-fpm cleanly, it just went back to normal.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This technique for debugging php-fpm via cgi-fcgi was very helpful, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The error message “Primary script unknown or in your case is file not found.” is almost always related to a wrongly set in line SCRIPT_FILENAME in the Nginx fastcgi_param directive (Quote from https://serverfault.com/a/517327/560171).

In my case, I use Nginx 1.17.10 and my configuration is:

```
    location ~ \.php$ {
      fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
      fastcgi_index index.php;
      fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
      include fastcgi_params;
      fastcgi_read_timeout 600;
    }
```

You just change $document_root to $realpath_root, so whatever your root location, like `/var/www/html/project/`, you don't need write `fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/html/project$fastcgi_script_name;` each time your root is changes. This configuration is more flexible. May this helps.

=================================================================================

For more information, if you got `unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock failed (13: Permission denied) while connecting to upstream`, just change in `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`, from `user nginx;` to `user www-data;`.

Because the default user and group of PHP-FPM process is www-data as can be seen in `/etc/php/7.2/fpm/pool.d/www.conf` file (Qoute from https://www.linuxbabe.com/ubuntu/install-nginx-latest-version-ubuntu-18-04):

```
user = www-data
group = www-data
```

May this information gives a big help

Answer (score 2):

In my case the PHP-script itself returned 404 code. Had nothing to do with nginx.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, it was because the permissions on the root web directory were not set correctly. To do this, you need to be in the parent folder when you run this in terminal:

```
sudo chmod -R 755 htmlfoldername
```

This will chmod all files in your html folder, which is not recommended for production for security reasons, but should let you see the files in that folder, to be sure that isn't the issue while troubleshooting.

Answer (score 1):

I had this error as well. In my case it was because there was another virtual host that was pointing to the same root directory.

Answer (score 1):

After upgrading to PHP72, we had an issue where the php-fpm.d/www.conf lost the settings for user/group which was causing this error. Be sure to double check those if your setup involves php-fpm.

Answer (score 0):

For me, problem was Typo in location path.

Maybe first thing to check out for this kind of problem

Is path to project.

Answer (score 0):

When getting "File not found", my problem was that there was no symlink in the folder where was pointing this line in ngix config:

```
root /var/www/claims/web;
```

Answer (score 0):

in case it helps someone, my issue seems to be just because I was using a subfolder under my home directory, even though permissions seem correct and I don't have SELinux or anything like that.
changing it to be under /var/www/something/something made it work.

(if I ever found the real cause, and remember this answer, I'll update it)

Answer (score 0):

try this command

```
sudo chmod 755 -R htdocs/
```

Answer (score 0):

my case: I used relative dir

```
       location ~* \.(css|js)\.php$ {

            root ../dolibarr/htdocs;

            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_index index.php;

             include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
       }
```

this line did not work too : `fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /vagrant/www/p1/../p2/htdocs/core/js/lib_head.js.php;`

So I discovered `fastcgi_param` does not support relative path.

This works

```
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /vagrant/www/p2/htdocs/core/js/lib_head.js.php;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue in nginx version: nginx/1.21.3 PHP 7.4.23 macOS Catalina version 10.15.7

```
nano /usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf


location ~ \.php$ {
            root           html;
            include        fastcgi.conf; 
            fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            #Comment bellow Line
            #fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
            #Add This line
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include        fastcgi_params;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, this File not found problem was because i started php-fpm as sudo. First, stop it as sudo and then start without sudo.