# centos7 use service php-fpm start "Primary script unknown"

Tags: php, nginx, centos7

I use **nginx+php-fpm** on centos7, when I use default root **/usr/share/nginx/html/** is worked, but i change root to other directory, for example **/usr/share/nginx/test/** is not work
And I cat **/var/log/nginx/error.log** **"Primary script unknown"**, so I try **chmod 777 -R /usr/share/nginx/test**, But the problem still exists， I try stop php-fpm service and Modify the nginx configuration file does not resolve php, then nginx get the correct php file.

now I use **php-fpm -D** is worked! so I want to know the different between "service php-fpm" and "php-fpm -D", why **php-fpm -D** can work?

env:
centos 7
php5.4
nginx

I'm very Sorry for my poor English！

Comment: Possible duplicate of [File Not Found when running PHP with Nginx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17808787/file-not-found-when-running-php-with-nginx)

Comment: I have solved this problem, The reason is selinux......