# Apache sends 'File not found' on all pages

Tags: php, laravel, apache

I'm using Laravel and when I uploaded the project to the server it returned 500, 503 and other types of errors. Because I'm using `Virtualmin` I checked the error_log in `/var/log/virtualmin` and I found that `php-fpm` hadn't enabled. So I enabled that and get `File not found` error on all pages now!

So I added `ProxyErrorOverride on` into `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` file but then got `Not Found
The requested URL /index.php was not found on this server.` I commented it and added `<FilesMatch \.php$>
  SetHandler "proxy:fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000"
</FilesMatch>` but again it returned `File not found`.

Then I went into `/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf` and edited this part from `;chroot =` to `chroot = /home/mysite/public_html/public`. But no result :(

**UPDATE**

I don't have any `.htaccess` file in root folder but in public folder and inside this I have:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

**UPDATE 2**

[image: Screenshot of error]

**UPDATE 3**

I modified `/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf`

from this:

```
user = apache
group = apache
```

to this:

```
user = php-fpm
group = php-fpm
```

from this:

```
listen = 127.0.0.1:9000
;listen = /run/php-fpm/www.sock
```

to this:

```
;listen = 127.0.0.1:9000
listen = /run/php-fpm/www.sock
```

and vice-versa.

from this:

```
listen.owner = apache
listen.group = apache
```

to this:

```
listen.owner = php-fpm
listen.group = php-fpm
```

from this:

```
;listen.acl_users = apache,nginx
```

to this:

```
listen.acl_users = apache,nginx
```

from this:

```
;listen.allowed_clients = 127.0.0.1
```

to this:

```
listen.allowed_clients = any
```

from this:

```
;chroot = /
```

to this:

```
chroot = /home/mysite/public_html
```

from this:

```
;chdir = /
```

to this:

```
chdir = /public
```

Sorry I said each one separately because I did it with various changes, each one may be varied on each time on changing values.

and now the Error is:

```
Service Unavailable
The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.
```

and my error_log:

```
[Thu Feb 21 02:58:13.318048 2019] [proxy:error] [pid 4170] (111)Connection refused: AH00957: FCGI: attempt to connect to 127.0.0.1:9000 (127.0.0.1) failed
[Thu Feb 21 02:58:13.318146 2019] [proxy:error] [pid 4170] AH00959: ap_proxy_connect_backend disabling worker for (127.0.0.1) for 60s
[Thu Feb 21 02:58:13.318155 2019] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 4170] [client 69.689.30.21:64560] AH01079: failed to make connection to backend: 127.0.0.1
```

**PLEASE HELP ME**

Comment: Can you please go through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17808787/file-not-found-when-running-php-with-nginx) thread to see anything missed out which is present in answers?

Comment: Because I don't know about nginx I didn't get the answers. BTW I'm using apache and I really don't know how php-fpm works. So modifications I did: `fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME /home/mysite/public_html/public$fastcgi_script_name;`, `fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    /home/mysite/public_html$fastcgi_script_name;`, `fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    /usr/share/nginx/html$fastcgi_script_name;` in `fastcgi.conf`. and in `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` I copied what Laravel recommended:

Comment: server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mysite.com;
    root /mysite.com/public; // and other lines as default
}

Comment: I am sorry my bad I did not notice you mentioned apache :)  But you can cross check  the fpm settings from the link though

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same error and just figured out the reason by strugling almost a whole day.

In my case, the problem was having IP v6 enabled in my vps while there was npo real IP6 address assigned into my interface.

I just dissabled the IPV6 and things started work normal again. (Dissable IPv6/IPv4 if it is not in use in virtualmin)

step 1 - edit the sysctl.conf file using the following command in your shell

```
vi /etc/sysctl.conf
```

step 2 - add the following two lines to dissable IPv6

```
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
```

step 3 - save and close the file (Esc -> :wq)

step 4 - for immediate effect run the following code in shell

```
sysctl -p
```